# How to extend mef using custom attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, prism, mef

Is it possible to add some additional attributes to my components which are then set/hydrated using some custom logic/perhaps from a data store? Similar to adding some custom builder strategy in cab/unity ?

UPDATE
e.g.

```
assuming a class has these properties

[MyImport]  string name1 { get; set }
[MyImport]  MyType name2 { get; set }
[MyGuid]  Guid { get; set; }
```

with custom attributes MyImport and MyGuid which are resolved by an "extension" to MEF ( which gets executed after the [imports] are resolved ) and has code along these lines

```
// property SET
var valu = myDBStore.GetValue( instanceGUID, propertyInfo.Name);
propertyInfo.SetValue( instance, TypeDescripter.GetConverter(valu).ConvertTo(propertyType), null);

// property GET - for example only, used during dehydration outside of MEF !
var valu = propertyInfo.GetValue( instance, null);
myDBStore.SetValue( instanceGUID, propertyInfo.Name, TypeDescripter.GetConverter(valu).ConvertTo(typeof(string));

// the above is pseudo code only, pls no comments on correct args/syntax :)
```

Comment: Hi - some clarification of what you're trying to achieve might help here.

Comment: Kumar,  out-of-the-box MEF may be able to solve your **underlying** problem.  However, the problem is still not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

`components which are then set/hydrated using some custom logic/perhaps from a data store`

One can do this via an "ExportFactory".

```
// "ExportFactory"
public sealed class DataStoreProvider
{
    [Export(typeof(Model))]
    public Model Item
    {
        get 
        {
            return [custom logic];
        }
    }
}

public class NeedsModel
{
    [Import(typeof(Model))]
    public Model Item { get; set; }
}
```

---

*Initial Answer*
This is possible through MEF's `Lazy<T, TMetadata>`.

```
public interface ISomeMetadata
{
    string UsefulInfo { get; }
}

[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple=false)]
public class ExportBaseAttribute : ExportAttribute, ISomeMetadata
{
    public ExportBaseAttribute(string usefulInfo)
        :base(typeof(BaseExport))
    {
        UsefulInfo = usefulInfo;
    }
    public string UsefulInfo { get; private set; }
}

// BaseExport class is not needed.. just showing advanced attribute usage.
public abstract class BaseExport { }

[ExportBase("Useful Filter Information")]
public class SomeExport : BaseExport
{
}
```

Then, in your host (composer), you can

```
[ImportMany(typeof(BaseExport))]
Lazy<BaseExport, ISomeMetadata>[] _baseExports
```

After you compose, you can run a LINQ filter using `.Metadata`

```
var goodExports = from export in _baseExports
                  where export.Metadata.UsefulInfo ...
                  select export;
```

Comment: the example has the custom attribute as a marker and the useful data there is string and MyType, also each type defines its custom properties so there is no common abstraction/interface like ISomeMetadata

Comment: @Kumar: your updated question is quite different than initially perceived.  This doesn't really seem like an `"extension" to MEF`, rather it seems like something you'd do _after composition_.

Comment: it can be done post composition but it'd be nice to make this a part of the "process" !

Comment: Hmm, can DataStoreProvider access a property of NeedoItem ( Guid ) used to return the custom value ? also is this DataStoreProvider.Export "called" in the end or any way to ensure it,s called in/towards the end ( so it can rely on the guid being there )

Comment: @Kumar: From an outsider's perspective... why are you so stickler on it being filled "in the end"?

Comment: let me try again the return [custom logic]; line relies on an additional piece of info ( guid ) as explained in my prev comment to work!! apologies for not being clear earlier!

Comment: Can you MEF Import the GUID (into DataStoreProvider
)? Or, are there limitations (if so, what are the limitations)?

Comment: the guid is at the NeedsModel level in your sample, not DataStoreProvider